# cannot update melpa `M-x package-refresh-contents`

Tags: package-repositories, emacs-mac-port

I am a relative emacs-noob, but for a long time my emacs setup relying on `use-package` worked well. It still does, but I recently looked into using a few more packages and after following a trail of errors I found out that I can no longer access MELPA to upgrade/download/etc packages. Emacs fully works and doesn't complain until I want to do anything package management related.

I've narrowed it down to running `M-x package-refresh-contents` which gives me these messages:

```
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Failed to download ‘melpa’ archive.
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
Package refresh done
Failed to download ‘nongnu’ archive.
```

Which means I'm stuck with my old, local MELPA tree from the past and obviously can't get any new things working. Running the command after `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` gives me the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "/opt/homebrew/bin")
  signal(wrong-type-argument (listp "/opt/homebrew/bin"))
  package--with-response-buffer-1("https://melpa.org/packages/" #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x156adc8adc58f9d3>) :file "archive-contents" :async nil :error-function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x20fd81f8bb468e1>) :noerror nil)
  package--download-one-archive(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
  package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
  package-refresh-contents()
  funcall-interactively(package-refresh-contents)
  call-interactively(package-refresh-contents record nil)
  command-execute(package-refresh-contents record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-refre")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-refre")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

But accessing MELPA with a browser or other way works:

```
curl -i https://melpa.org/packages/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
[...]
```

It seems to me like something changed/broke my homebrew backend and emacs can't find whatever it's using to access MELPA in `/opt/homebrew/bin`? I run MacOS and homebrew everything, using `railwaycat/emacs-mac` as my emacs provider:

```
GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113.6) 
 of 2022-09-15
```

As it did work in the past, I do not believe it's an issue with my config, but for completeness, here's the relevant section of my `init.el`:

```
;; https://ianyepan.github.io/posts/setting-up-use-package/
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-and-compile
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t
    ; speedup startup time by only loading use-packages when needed
    use-package-always-defer t
    ; set to t for debugging 
    use-package-verbose nil
    use-package-expand-minimally t))

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
```

Any help on where to look at, or how to get better logs on what exactly emacs is missing from my homebrew bins would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try with `emacs -q -l min.el` with a minimal init file that just sets up the package archives. I suspect that it's either something in your init file (bisect it to figure out what) or your current emacs session is curdled somehow: it's unclear where `"/opt/homebrew/bin"`  is coming from.

Comment: what @NickD said. check everywhere in your config you have `/opt/homebrew/bin`. you shouldn't really need it for anything except maybe `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin")`, and even that's not necessary for using packages.

Comment: Ah, thanks, this did solve the MELPA part! I had this in my config: 

`(when (string-equal system-type "darwin")
   (setq exec-path (append exec-path '"/opt/homebrew/bin")))`

commenting it resolves the issue. Now, I _think_ I had needed that for aspell to work on mac, but I'll investigate further. I wonder why it messed up internals, though?

Comment: Did you try restarting emacs? And setting `exec-path` as you do is wrong: you should use `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin" t)` to add the element to the end. The way you do it makes `exec-path` an improper list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment

```lisp
;; I had this in my config:
(when (string-equal system-type "darwin")
    (setq exec-path (append exec-path '"/opt/homebrew/bin")))
```

You've "double quoted" the string `"/opt/homebrew/bin"`. Drop the apostrophe, and things will work as you expect.

If you're not purposefully trying to re-order `exec-path` you may want to think about using `add-to-list` instead of doing an append-and-self-assign. `add-to-list` will prepend (by default) or append (optionally) to a list if the element does not already exist in the list. It's a handy way to keep lists like paths tidy.

---

Note that if you have added Homebrew to your path in your `~/.zshev` then launching Emacs from Finder/Launchpad/Dock, via `open -a Emacs`, or a symlink or direct call in your terminal should all work as you expect *without* touching `exec-path`. That being said I do something like the following:

```bash
# ~/.zshenv
# make sure Finder/Launchpad can find Homebrew stuff
if [[ -x /opt/homebrew/bin/brew ]]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:${PATH}
fi

# ~/.zshrc
# add Homebrew convenience vars, and add to PATH/INFOPATH/MANPATH 
eval $(brew shellenv)
```

and

```lisp
;; ~/.emacs/init.el
;; exec-path, not strictly necessary, but doesn't hurt
;; load-path, use cmake's cmake-mode.el not emacs's
(cond ((string-match-p "aarch64-apple" system-configuration)
       (add-to-list 'load-path "/opt/homebrew/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake")
       (add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin"))
      ((string-match-p "x86_64-apple" system-configuration)
       (add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake")
       (add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in-depth answer and help! Yes, d'oh... I see the superfluous `'` now... I tested around today and I did indeed not need the `exec-path` part at all. That's probably why it never triggered any errors.